Maximum Sum Without Skipping Two Contiguous Elements
The task is to find the maximum sum of a subsequence of integers from a given list. The subsequence must follow two conditions:

It must be contiguous, meaning the selected elements are in consecutive order from the original list.
At most one element can be skipped consecutively. In other words, no more than one element can be skipped in a row.

For example, if given the list [-3, 2, 4, -1, -2, -5], the maximal sum can be obtained by selecting [2, 4, -2], resulting in a sum of 4.
In another example, for the list [9, -1, -3, 4, 5], the maximum sum is 17.
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr={9,-1,-3,4,5};
        int n=arr.length;
        System.out.print(solve(n-1,arr,0));
    }
public static int solve(int ind,int[] arr,int skip){
        if(ind==-1 && skip==0)
        return arr[ind+1];
        
        if(ind==-1 && skip==1)
        return 0;
        
        if(skip>1)
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        
        int notpick=0;
        int pick=arr[ind]+solve(ind-1,arr,0);
        if(skip<2)
        notpick=solve(ind-1,arr,skip+1);
        
        return Math.max(pick,notpick);
    }

i tried in a recursive approach,from the above i was able to succeed first example,but getting different output for second example i.e for the array [9, -1, -3, 4, 5].iam getting 26 as output instead of 17.what's wrong in my approach.is my entire logic is wrong?what changes should be done?

"the maximal sum can be obtained by selecting [2, 4, -2]": why is [2, 4, -1] not a candidate (with greater sum)? And why not just [2, 4]?

@trincot,if you select only [2,4,-1],you are leaving/skipping last two elements,which should not be done

Oh, so the subsequence must span the whole input (including the skips)? I see... that was not clear to me from the description.

the very similar question as this deleted one but a different user!?! even tagged with Python and Java

A recursive approach could work by replacing the items you remove with None and using that as a flag to exclude removal of None neighbours.  You only need to remove negative numbers because positive ones will always make the sum higher.
For example:
def solve(A):
    result = sum(filter(None,A))
    for i,n in enumerate(A):
        if not n or n > 0: continue                 # keep positives and None
        if i and A[i-1] is None: continue           # keep None neighbours 
        if i+1<len(A) and A[i+1] is None: continue
        result = max(result,solve(A[:i]+[None]+A[i+1:])) # remove & recurse
    return result

output:
print(solve([-3, 2, 4, -1, -2, -5])) # 4
print(solve([9, -1, -3, 4, 5]))      # 17

Note that this is less efficient than your approach because recursion will re-evaluate combinations on the left of the skipped items.
Recursing based on the skipped and non-skipped alternatives would be more efficient, and shorter:
def solve(A):
    return max(A[0]+solve(A[1:]), sum(A[1:2])+solve(A[2:])) if A else 0

An you can also optimize it to never skip a positive number:
def solve(A):
    if not A: 
         return 0
    result = A[0]+solve(A[1:])
    if A[0]<0:
        result = max( result, sum(A[1:2])+solve(A[2:]) )
    return result


The cause of the wrong output for one of the example inputs is in this statement:
return arr[ind + 1];

It will take into a account a value that was already (potentially) taken into account when the recursive call was made, in this context:
arr[ind] + solve(ind - 1, arr, 0);

This arr[ind] is the same value as the arr[ind + 1] in the base case. In the example input it represents the value 9, which gets double counted.
The solution is to just return 0 when ind == -1 without further conditions.
Not a problem, but you're over-complicating it by allowing skip to take any other value than 0 or 1. In fact, it could just be a boolean.
Here is your code with those changes applied and some "cosmetic" changes:
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {9, -1, -3, 4, 5};
        System.out.print(solve(arr.length - 1, arr, false));
    }

    public static int solve(int ind, int[] arr, boolean skip) {
        if (ind == -1) {
            return 0;
        }
        int pick = arr[ind] + solve(ind - 1, arr, false);
        if (skip) {
            return pick;
        }
        int notpick = solve(ind - 1, arr, true);
        return Math.max(pick, notpick);
    }
}

Efficiency concerns
The above does not have a good time complexity because the recursion tree is a binary tree, and so the number of function executions is exponential.
You could resolve this with using memoization. Or you could use bottom-up tabulation, realising there are always only two results you need: the sum where the next value was excluded, and the one where it was included:
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {9, -1, -3, 4, 5};
        System.out.print(solve(arr));
    }

    public static int solve(int[] arr) {
        int sumWithoutNext = 0;
        int sumWithNext = 0;
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int bestSum = Math.max(sumWithoutNext, sumWithNext);
            sumWithoutNext = sumWithNext;
            sumWithNext = arr[i] + bestSum;
        }
        return Math.max(sumWithoutNext, sumWithNext);
    }
}

This has linear time complexity.

can you convert it into tabulation

The bottom solution is the one with tabulation. The table has just two values... contained in the two sum* variables.

@trincot has answered your question (and more), so I will simply suggest an alternative calculation.
This solution is in Ruby, which I believe could be translated to Python quite easily.
def max_sum(arr)
  return 0 if arr.empty?
  h = { skip: 0, include: 0 }
  arr.each do |n|
    prev_skip = h[:skip] 
    h[:skip] = h[:include]
    h[:include] = n + [prev_skip, h[:include]].max
  end
  [h[:skip], h[:include]].max
end

max_sum([-3, 2, 4, -1, -2, -5])
  #=> 4
max_sum([9, -1, -3, 4, 5]
  #=> 17
max_sum([])
  #=> 0
max_sum([-2])
  #=> 0
max_sum([-2,3])
  #=> 3
max_sum([-2,-3])
  #=> -2


h is a hash. h[:skip] is the value of the key (a symbol) :skip; h[:include] is the value of the key :include.
Assume n = arr[i], i > 0.
The assignment
h[:skip] = h[:include]

says that if n is skipped, the best value for arr[j], 0 <= j <= i will be the best value after arr[i-1] was included.
The assignment
h[:include] = n + [prev_skip, h[:include]].max

says that if n of arr is included, the best value for arr[j], 0 <= j <= i equals n plus the greater of the best value after element arr[i-1] was skipped and the best value after that element was included.
The temporary variable prev_skip is needed because h[:skip] is updated before h[:include] is updated.

The Ruby way of writing the method above is slightly more concise.
def max_sum(arr)
  return 0 if arr.empty?
  arr.each_with_object({ skip: 0, include: 0 }) do |n,h|
    prev_skip = h[:skip] 
    h[:skip] = h[:include]
    h[:include] = n + [prev_skip, h[:include]].max
  end.max
end

